# Play Scala Post Redirect Get Pattern - Redirect to a View

Tags: scala, playframework

This is a noob question for Play 2.5.

I have a simple Action that (eventually) deletes an element from the table.
This Action is triggered by a route that is defined as a POST.

```
POST /delete/:id            @com.test.controllers.XController.delete(id: String)
```

When the delete is successful, the code currently resolves to a view named 'success' (internally a success.scala.html with a custom message parameter and on optional object).

```
Future.successful(Ok(success(Some("Item was deleted"), customObject)))
```

However, the user can still try and press F5 to refresh the page, thereby submitting the form once again. To avoid this, one option is to redirect to the "success" view.

I cannot, for the love of God, figure out how to Redirect to this view. It seems that you can only Redirect via a reverse route, or using URLs.

Comment: Did you try: `Future.successful(Redirect(newUrl))`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As stated, that is an option I did not want to take.

Answer (score 0):

First approach if you need to play forms ([link on spec](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaForms)):
you can pass parameter directly:

```
 val df = form().bindFromRequest()
 return redirect(routes.Application.somePlace(df.get("action"), 
 df.get("id")))
```

If you don't need Scala forms, you can make [redirect](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaRouting) via `Redirect`:

```
GET   /hello/:name          controllers.Application.hello(name)
// Redirect to /hello/Bob
def helloBob = Action {
    Redirect(routes.Application.hello("Bob"))    
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have a view called "success" which takes parameters. It does not appear on "routes" because it is not a route. Having a URL would mean I would need to figure out what the URL for the "success" is.

Comment: if you want make the redirect on form handler try something like this:
 `userData =>{Redirect(routes.Application.home(models.User.create(newUser)))}`